# location of an Accesspoint is not updated

Tags: here-api

I am using the positionning v2 API to locate some assetes using mac Addresses of Accesspoints. It is working well, but sometimes a mac address is not located where it is supposed to. So when I try to locate a position with 5-6 mac Addresses (the location of 1 mac Address is not correct), the API give me that message :

> 'title': 'Not Found', 'status': 404, 'code': 'E606404', 'action': 'The values provided in the request cannot produce any content for the response. The location of the WLANs and cells in the request is unknown or the locations of the radio measurements are so widely scattered that the location cannot be determined. Make sure that the network measurements are correct and consistent. Try allowing fallbacks `area` or `any` for cell positioning and `singleWifi` for WLAN positioning.', 'cause': 'Position not found'

How can I bypass that kind of error?

Here is the code :

```py
data = {
    "wlan": []
}

#for wifi in networks:
entry = {
    "mac": "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
    "rss": -42
}
data["wlan"].append(entry)

entry1 = {
    "mac": "yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy",
    "rss": -54
}
data["wlan"].append(entry1)

entry2 = {
    "mac": "zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:zz",
    "rss": -76
}
data["wlan"].append(entry2)

#This mac address is not well located (400 kms difference from the real position)
#entry3 = {
#    "mac": "vv:vv:vv:vv:vv:vv",
#    "rss": -64
#}
#data["wlan"].append(entry3)

import json
import requests

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
url = "https://positioning.hereapi.com/v2/locate?apiKey=" + "my_api_key" + "&desired=altitude" + "&fallback=singleWifi"
print(data)
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with below sample code. And for best results please follow the  tips defined in the document link:
Doc Link:  https://developer.here.com/documentation/positioning-api/dev_guide/topics/tips-for-data-accuracy.html

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://positioning.hereapi.com/v2/locate?apiKey={your_api_key}&desired=altitude&fallback=singleWifi"

payload = json.dumps({
  "wlan": [
    {
      "mac": "xxxxxx"
    },
    {
      "mac": "xxxxxx"
    }
  ]
})
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```